# jQuery AJAX JSON response returns key "d"

Tags: json, asp.net-ajax, jquery, get

When I make a jQuery AJAX JSON request, it responds with a "d" attribute.

Why is this?

Comment: supposedly MS added it to protect against a particularly XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

here a good article about it http://encosia.com/2009/06/29/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/

> “.d” what? If you aren’t familiar with the “.d” I’m referring to, it
>   is simply a security feature that Microsoft added in ASP.NET 3.5’s
>   version of ASP.NET AJAX. By encapsulating the JSON response within a
>   parent object, the framework helps protect against a particularly
>   nasty XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise it was ASP.NET specific which is why I originally didn't tag it with anything to do with asp.net! Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

If you aren’t familiar with the “.d” I’m referring to, it is simply a security feature that Microsoft added in ASP.NET 3.5’s version of ASP.NET AJAX. By encapsulating the JSON response within a parent object, the framework helps protect against a particularly nasty XSS vulnerability.