# AJAX returning Undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Please see the code below from my MVC view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetMessage() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost/webapi/api/Values/",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess(),
                async: false,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert('there was an error creating the disposal decision records')
                }
            });

            function OnSuccess() {
                return function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            }
        }
        GetMessage();
    </script>
```

and the code from: http://localhost/webapi/api/Values/ :

```
public Person Get()
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.id = 1;
            p.name = "Bert";
            p.age = 31
            return p;
        }
```

In the Success event handler; undefined is prompted. Why?

Comment: What is `response.d`?

Comment: @Nic, please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215386/jquery-ajax-json-response-returns-key-d

Comment: Try `console.log(response)` and see what it contains. Alert isn't very good for debugging.

Comment: And did you open your console to check for errors, for instance a "parse error".

Comment: Your response is a serialization of `Person` which does not contain a property named `d`. To alert "Bert", use `alert(response.name );`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke.  Please see my first comment above, which contains a link.  That explains why I used: Response.d.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are working with WebApi or any rest web service, you must test it in browser before you do it with jquery-ajax

First you need to please try http://localhost/webapi/api/Values/ in browser (to be sure your server side is OK, as it does not need your jquery ajax code). Probably you would not get desired result.

---

Now in any case you need some fixes with your ajax request please do following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var OnSuccess = function(data)
    {
         alert("this is success"); // just check if this works
         alert(data); // just check if this works
         if(data && data.d)
            alert(data.d);
    }

    function GetMessage() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost/webapi/api/Values/",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            async: false,
            error:function(er){ 
                 alert(er.responseText);
            }                
        });

        function OnSuccess() {
            return function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        }
    }
    GetMessage();
</script>
```

---

If http://localhost/webapi/api/Values/ works in browser for you then ajax also must be doing fine after above fixes. But if it does not, then you need to look into following

It seems that your server side is not OK yet. Your server side controller must have code like

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Values")]
public class PersonssController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/Values
    [Route("")]
    public Person Get() { 
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.id = 1;
        p.name = "Bert";
        p.age = 31
        return p;
    }    
}
```

---

After above changes in your webapi controller, now you should be able to find http://localhost/webapi/api/Values/ working fine in browser, and as you have also changed your jquery request as I told at top, so all must be fine

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    var OnSuccess = function(response) {
       alert(response.d);
    }
```

and in your ajax call:

```
success: OnSuccess,
```